# Running app delegate code from a View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, appdelegate

I'm following along with a guide that creates faux push notifications and the code is something like this..

In the App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions he sets up the notification settings, registers the settings, sets up the priority and then goes into:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0),{


//in here he checks for a change in his firebase data

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

  //sets up his UILocalNotification here

}
```

the way that the notification is getting triggered is by observing firebase within the app delegate.

I'm looking to take this same concept but trigger setting up the notification from a button press from a view controller.

If I've got a UIAction in my viewcontroller for a button how can I then trigger the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in my appdelegate?

I tried doing something like

```
  if let myDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
        myDelegate.setUpNotification()
    }
}
```

and wrapped all of the stuff under didFinishLaunching that had to do with notifications under setUpNotification(){}, but then it wasn't accessable to my VC.

Comment: what you've done looks right to me and it should work if you've implemented the function properly. can you show the way you have done this in the app delegate?

Comment: Can you expand on _but then it wasn't accessable to my VC_?

Comment: Moved some stuff around and it works as I've got it in the edit. I was just being blind. Thanks folks!